# How to audjust my "folding a paper to the moon" code

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm building a code in Javascript that will calculate how many times I will have to fold a paper so that its thickness will reach the moon.

(it is suppose to be a known challenge)

Thick parameters is the Thickness of the paper
numOfLayers parameter states how many layers have been pilled up:

But I get the wrong results:

```
Milimeters = Thick*numOfLayers;
Centimeters = Thick*numOfLayers/10;
Meters = Thick*numOfLayers/100;
Kilometers = Thick*numOfLayers/1000;
```

this is my calculation here.
What am I calculating wrong?

Comment: I'm pleasantly surprised to find that you can hold the number of millimeters to the moon in a JavaScript number without exceeding `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. The distance varies, but the mean is 384,402km, which is 384,402,000,000mm. Nowhere near `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9,007,199,254,740,991). :-)

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). *"What am I calculating wrong?"* What makes you think you are? What result do you get, and what result do you expect instead?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In what way is this not a good question? OP provided ample background information regarding what they are actually trying to do and provided an exact snippet of code which shows how the calculation is performed. The only thing that would improve the question are the results of the calculation and what values are expected, though that information is not hard to deduce from the provided information.

Comment: @JamesCoyle - The issue is as I said in the comment: The OP is saying the results are wrong. Any time you say that, it's important to say what results you were expecting, and what results you're getting instead. That way, answerers can be sure that their answers are correct. I can't count the number of times I've guessed what the OP thought was wrong, only to find that no, it was something else entirely. This isn't remotely the worst example (and I'm pleased not to see any downvotes), but it still should be fixed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, You are right, In this case, I actually meant what I wrote in terms of the calculation. It appeared to be a math problem - I answered my self with the entire code and gave my self a comment that answers the issue you were referring. thank you for that.

Answer (score 3):

You are using millimeters for all of the other calculations. You probably want to pass the previous value into the subsequent calculation or adjust the divisors appropriately.

```js
Milimeters = Thick * numOfLayers;
Centimeters = Milimeters / 10;
Meters = Centimeters / 100;
Kilometers = Meters / 1000;
```

---

**Example**

```js
const thick = 0.1
const layers = 100000000

let millimeters, centimeters, meters, kilometers

// broken
millimeters = thick * layers
centimeters = thick * layers / 10
meters = thick * layers / 100
kilometers = thick * layers / 1000

console.log("Broken", millimeters + 'mm', centimeters + 'cm', meters + 'm', kilometers + 'km') 


// fixed 
millimeters = thick * layers
centimeters = millimeters / 10
meters = centimeters / 100
kilometers = meters / 1000

console.log("Fixed", millimeters + 'mm', centimeters + 'cm', meters + 'm', kilometers + 'km') 


// fixed with divisors
millimeters = thick * layers
centimeters = millimeters / 10
meters = millimeters / 1000
kilometers = millimeters / 1000000

console.log("Fixed Divisors", millimeters + 'mm', centimeters + 'cm', meters + 'm', kilometers + 'km')
```

Comment: This answer is still wrong. You are doing what I did and it is a mistake. :-) (yap, I got confused too) - Check my answer - I replied my self with the full code and gave it a comment with the issue that is now solved being explained.

Comment: @marble My answer is not wrong at all. All you have done in your answer is follow my second suggestion to `adjust the divisors appropriately`. I provided code for the alternative solution to calculate the value based on the previous calculation.

Comment: I've edited to add the divisor fix as an example in the snippet too.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}
</style>

<script>

function showTable(orbitDistant, paperThicknes)
{
    var layers = 1;
    var liner="";

    var mm = 0;
    var cm = 0;
    var m  = 0;
    var km = 0;

    var i = 0;

    while ((paperThicknes*layers/1000000) < (orbitDistant*2)) //*2 to make sure it wont stop before it reaches the figure
    {
        mm = (paperThicknes*layers).toLocaleString('en');
        cm = (paperThicknes*layers/10).toLocaleString('en');
        m  = (paperThicknes*layers/1000).toLocaleString('en');
        km = (paperThicknes*layers/1000000).toLocaleString('en');

        layers_en = (layers).toLocaleString('en');

        liner = "<tr><td>"+i+"</td><td>"+layers_en+"</td><td>"+mm+"</td><td>"+cm+"</td><td>"+m+"</td><td>"+km+"</td></tr>";

        $('#mt tr:last').after("<tr>"+liner+"</tr>");

        layers = layers * 2;

        i++;
    }
}

function initDiv(distantKM, paperThicknes)
{
    $("#mainDiv").html('<table id="mt"><tr><td>num of folds</td><td>num of layers</td><td>thickness in mm</td><td>thickness in cm</td><td>thickness in m</td><td>thickness in km</td></tr></table>');
    showTable(distantKM, paperThicknes);
    $("#distantKM").html((Number(distantKM)).toLocaleString('en'));
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    initDiv(384400, 0.0916);

    $('#selectDistant').on('change', function() {
      var distantKM = $("#selectDistant").val();
      var thicknesMM = $("#selectThicknes").val();
      initDiv(distantKM, thicknesMM);
    });

    $('#selectThicknes').on('change', function() {
      var distantKM = $("#selectDistant").val();
      var thicknesMM = $("#selectThicknes").val();
      initDiv(distantKM, thicknesMM);
    });
});

//https://www.universetoday.com/14824/distance-from-earth-to-mars/

</script>

</head>

<body style="direction:rtl;">

                            <br>
<center>
<h1>Distant from earth to the 
<select id="selectDistant">
  <option selected value=384400>moon</option>
  <option value=56000000>mars</option> <!-- the closest they have ever been to each other -->
  <option value=149565511>sun</option>
</select> is <b><span id="distantKM">384,400</span></b> Kilometers</h1>

<h3>how many <select id="selectThicknes">
  <option selected value=0.0916>paper (millimeters 0.0916 thick)</option>
  <option value=1>carton (1 millimeter thick)</option> <!-- the closest they have ever been to each other -->
</select> folds will you need ?</h3>

<br />
<br />

<div id="mainDiv">
    <table id="mt">
    </table>
</div>

    <br />
    <br />

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the code. It is working great. I accidentally (and automatically) went up by only one zero each time I moved from millimeters to centimeters, to meters to kilometers. it was wrong. instead - it is 10->1,000->1,000,000

Comment: I got the wrong result because I missed a few Zeros. it was not a code issue because JS can apparently reach a very big Integer and I was left with understanding that it is a jump of more than one zero every time. now it is showing the exact distance so the calculation is working properly. You have the entire code (that wraps my issue) to prove that it is calculating it properly now.

Comment: This is what I meant by `adjust the divisors appropriately` in my answer...

Comment: :-) to end it up with a smile, lets agree that we both came up with 42 paper folds?